# vb.net PDF integration

Tags: vb.net, class, pdf

We have a database that has decompiled data versions of PDF files stored as blobs.

The old method to retrieve the information was to grab the blob, compile the file on the local disk, and then use process.start to launch the new .pdf file that was created.

I guess I am looking for a class that can accept the decompile PDF data, turn it into a compiled PDF and show the end results without having to save the file to the local disk.

Anyone have any suggestions?

thanks.

Comment: I have never heard of compiled PDFs, could you link to where these are described?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just create the stream and send that into a Document Viewer control for PDF. There are tons of PDF Viewer controls, as long as they support a DataStream you should be fine. I'd let the process compile the PDF File into memory as a File Stream and send it to the PDF viewer. I have done the same thing but to a Microsoft format like xps, and doc but as long as the viewer supports a file stream you should have no problem.

This pdf viewer has a cost, but it might help: http://www.gnostice.com/nl_article.asp?id=109 the example they show goes by filename but its possible it might support the data stream method. Most views do.

Comment: I like this id, im going to do some google searchs hopefully i can come up with something relevant. thanks

Comment: Sorry I can't direct you to an exact class. I'm unfamiliar with the method of decompiling pdf's, I've always used a class to generate my pdf's in memory and saved them to disk. I've worked with other document formats that are compatible with a .net Document Viewer object and I've always sent the compiled stream to the viewer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Run through all the compiled .pdfs with your old method and store them somewhere.

Comment: ie you mean store them on say our public server, whenever you want to view one, grab the file_name from the database and have it launch a path example \\file_server\certs\" & strfilename ?

Comment: sure, that would work.  yes, the idea is to batch the compilation results so you don't have to decompile on each request.